# How are these 2 classes related?

Tags: uml, associations

If you have an Arrival class and a Flight class where the Arrival class has all the information pertaining a Flight (the flight ID, eta, runway #, gate) coming in...would it be an association?

I'm a little confused as to what it could be since the Arrival class doesn't really have a purpose unless there is a flight so an arrival is related to the flight.

I can see it being both:
Arrival has a Flight (aggregation?)
Arrival uses/needs a Flight (dependence?)

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: An `Arrival` could be anything. You need to explain what it should be from you POV. Definitely it has a scheduled time, but what else?

Comment: @qwerty_so you're right maybe the way I worded it was not clear, I have edited the description

Comment: Ok. I think you should go with Cristian's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Flight class attributes are, but it looks like a composition relationship. The Flight has an Arrival and the Arrival can not exist without a Flight.

Comment: I didnt want to over complicate the question but the flight would have attributes that pertain to the flight such as ID, destination, origin, #passengers, etc..

Comment: The wording is "composite aggregation" as per UML 2.5, not just "composition". Pls. fix and I'll upvote.

Comment: @qwerty_so: There is no need to adopt the *committee jargon* of the OMG spec. Better use ordinary terms when available.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding your issue, one should not think in terms of UML, but rather take a look at how things are/work in the real world.

A particular flight, in the real world, is an activity that is composed of a departure event and an arrival event.

Consequently, if you capture flight types in the form of a class `Flight`, then a class `Arrival` is associated with `Flight` using a one-to-one composition (association) expressing the fact that a flight has an arrival as a component.